# NextJS Dynamic Routes: How to capture index.tsx

Tags: next.js

Is there a way to capture the "/" url from a dynamic route ?

Here's what I tried:

[image]

That gave me error 404 on "http://localhost:3000/" instead of going into the [...page] component.

Comment: Have you considered using [optional catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes)? It should capture the `/` path as well.

Answer (score 0):

the [...page].tsx will only capture the route after the / therefore http://localhost:3000/page1 or http://localhost:3000/page1/page2  will go into the [...page].tsx

and you can extract the values from nextjs router

```
import {useRouter} from "next/router";
```

then in your component

```
const router = useRouter()

console.log(router.query.page)
```